# Does unirationality over an infinite field imply infinitely many rational points?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an algebraic variety defined over a field $k$. We say that $X$ is unirational (over $k$) if there is a dominant rational map $$f\colon\mathbb{P}^n_k \dashrightarrow X$$ for some $n$. **If $k$ is infinite, does that imply that $X(k)$ is infinite?**

I was thinking that maybe all but finitely many points go to the generic point (assume $X$ is irreducible). Then $X(k)$ would be dense, I think. But I also read that often you can ignore non-closed points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In fact, even more is true:

> **Claim:** Let $k$ be an infinite field and let $X/k$ be a unirational variety. Then $X(k)$ is dense is dense in $X$. In particular, if $\dim X>0$ then $X(k)$ is infinite.

*Proof:* Let $f:\mathbb{P}^n_k\dashrightarrow X$ be a dominant rational map. In fact, let us pick an open $U\subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ on which $f:U\to X$ be a dominant map. Since $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ we know that $U(k)\subseteq U$ is dense (e.g. see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/264197/rational-points-on-open-subsets-of-affine-space)). Since $f(U)\subseteq X$ is dense (by assumption) and $f(U(k))$ is dense in $f(U)$ (since $f$ is continuous), we deduce that $f(U(k))$ is dense in $X$. Since $f(U(k))\subseteq X(k)$ this implies that $X(k)$ is dense in $X$ as desired.

The second claim follows since if $X(k)$ is finite, then since it's also closed (being a finite set of closed points), its closure is itself. Thus, $X=X(k)$ is finite so $\dim X=0$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: But why can't $X(k)$ be a finite set that includes the generic point (assuming $X$ is irreducible)? Why would each point in $X(k)$ have to be closed?

Comment: @Mehta Because $k$-points are always closed. Right? Like let $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ be an open in $X$ and let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a $k$-point. Note then that $A/\mathfrak{p}$ is a $k$-algebra for which we know that $\mathrm{Frac}(A/\mathfrak{p})$ is $k$. This forces $A/\mathfrak{p}$ to be $k$ so that $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal.